# Get json from sql using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I have a json string in my sql database.

`get_survey_results.php`

```
<?php

// including some cfg & functions
include_once("config.php");
include_once("funcs.php");

// setting connection and getting user id
$con = setConnection();
$hash = $_COOKIE['hash'];
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM `users` WHERE hash='$hash' LIMIT 1";
$result   = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
$id = -1;
if (sizeof($data) > 0) {
    $id = $data['user_id'];
}
// if user id is exist get jsonstring from database
if ($id > 0) {
    $q = "SELECT results FROM `survey_results` WHERE user_id='$id' LIMIT 1";
    $r   = mysqli_query($con, $q);
    $d = $r->fetch_assoc();
    echo json_decode($d['results']); // !!!
    // PS $d['results'] exist, it is a json string
    //  tried also echo $d['results'] but get no result
}
else {
    // otherwise get false, false is getting ok in responce, but not results above
    echo "false";
}

closeConnection($con);

?>
```

I want to return it in `JS` using `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var json
var data = new FormData()
// AJAX CALL
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('POST', "php/get_survey_results.php", true)
xhr.onload = function(){
    var jsonString = this.response
    console.log("JSON STRING IS")
    console.log(jsonString) // !!! returns empty
};
```

But it returns nothing in case user exist, otherwise returns false. I marked problem places as `!!!`

Comment: Use `fetch` to grab the `response.json()`. Make sure your request is asking for JSON data and that the PHP server is returning JSON.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl oh, I had several `user_id`s by mistake in my db and only the last of them has json string, that was the reason..